# How to tell if a lib was compiled with /mt or /md?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Given a compiled `lib`, is there a way to tell if it was compiled with `/md` or `/mt` just by looking at it (maybe with `dumpbin` tool)?

**Edit:**
`dumpbin /directives foo.lib` is a solution for the case where the `lib` was not compiled with `/GL` switch. Is there an option to inspect a `lib` file that was optimized in such a way?

Comment: Can you change the accepted answer since it doesn't work anymore and has less votes than the one below it?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Yes, you could use dumpbin's `/DIRECTIVES` option to find which runtime libraries the objects in the .lib want to link with:

```
dumpbin /directives foo.lib
```

Look for instances of the runtime libraries specified [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/abx4dbyh.aspx).  For example, you might see:

`/DEFAULTLIB:MSVCRTD` (module compiled with /MDd)

or

`/DEFAULTLIB:MSVCRT` (module compiled with /MD)

or

`/DEFAULTLIB:LIBCMT` (module compiled with /MT)

There will probably be many `/DEFAULTLIB` directives, so you can search using terms like:

```
dumpbin /DIRECTIVES foo.lib | find /i "msvcr"
```

Comment: `/DEFAULTLIB` is a switch for the linker - how can I output it with `dumpbin`?

Comment: /DEFAULTLIB:MSVCRTD   is an example of the output of dumpbin as Chris stated. It's also a linker directive.

Comment: this does not work anymore on visual studio 2017  as of march 2024 it just when process followed command prompt just say "file type: library"

Answer (score 14):

A very nice feature of the Microsoft compiler is that it preserves the command line that was used to compile a source file into the .obj file.  Which allows you to find it back by looking at the .lib file with, *wait for it*, Notepad.exe.  Just search for "cl.exe".

For example, this is what I see when I use Notepad opened on a sample library named Win32Project1.lib that I built with VS2013:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin\CL.exe cmd -c -ZI -nologo -W3 -WX- -sdl -Od -Oy- -DWIN32 -D_DEBUG -D_LIB -DHELLO_STACKOVERFLOW -D_UNICODE -DUNICODE -Gm -EHs -EHc -RTC1 -MDd -GS -fp:precise -Zc:wchar_t -Zc:forScope -Ycstdafx.h -Fp"c:\Users\hpass_000\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\Win32Project1\Debug\Win32Project1.pch" -Fo"c:\Users\hpass_000\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\Win32Project1\Debug\" -Fd"c:\Users\hpass_000\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\Win32Project1\Debug\vc120.pdb" -Gd -TP -analyze- -errorreport:prompt -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\atlmfc\include" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\shared" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\winrt" -X src stdafx.cpp pdb c:\Users\hpass_000\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\Win32Project1\Debug\vc120.pdb

As you can tell, I compiled with /MDd

Do beware that a .lib can contain multiple .obj files with possibly different settings.  Searching for "-mt" and "-md" lets you find out quickly.

Comment: This is awesome! I took it one step ahead with sysinternal's "strings.exe" tool

Comment: This doesnt seem to be true anymore, neither of .lib, .obj nor .exe (ie. trying protobuf 2.6.1 in VS2013)

Comment: @FernandoGonzalezSanchez, the same is true for VS2017