# How I find out Compiler flags from a .lib file built using Visual Studio

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

Is there a way to find out the compiler flags that were used in the building of a static library? I am using Visual Studio 2013.
I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19487465/how-to-tell-if-a-lib-was-compiled-with-mt-or-md), but the directives option does not give the compiler flags such as /GL etc.,

Comment: Tried the other comment, opening it with a text editor?

Comment: yes - but there is no such information in the file

Answer (score 0):

Use dumpbin.exe https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/177429 to find out the information you need. It is a free tool from Microsoft.

Comment: Any specifics on what option to use with dumpbin?

Comment: - dumpbin /ARCHIVEMEMBERS <your_lib_name>.lib  
  
- dumpbin /EXPORTS <your_lib_name>.lib  

You can run these from the command prompt or Visual Studio command window.