# Linker warning: uuid.lib(unknwn_i.obj) : MSIL .netmodule or module compiled with /GL found; restarting link with /LTCG

Tags: windows, visual-studio, linker, visual-studio-2015

I have a Visual C++ solution with static and dynamic libraries, and one executable that uses these libraries. I'm currently upgrading from Visual Studio 2010 to Visual Studio 2015, I also upgraded the SDK version the projects use to 10.0.10586.0 (Windows 10).

Everything compiles and links correctly, except for one linker warning:

```
uuid.lib(unknwn_i.obj) : MSIL .netmodule or module compiled with /GL found; restarting link with /LTCG; add /LTCG to the link command line to improve linker performance
```

`uuid.lib` is part of the Windows SDK. It might have been compiled with `/GL`, but does that mean that every executable that gets linked against this library *must* use `/GL`? That would be pretty constraining. By the way, if I switch to Windows SDK version 8.1 (but still using Visual Studio 2015), the warning goes away.

I have a feeling that something else might be wrong here (even though the linker points to a very specific location), because I found zero Google references of this particular error with this particular object file, which is very strange...

Any ideas?

**Edit:**

- The warning is present in both Debug and Release builds
- According to link.exe with `/VERBOSE`, X.obj (and only that object) in my executable project is referencing unknwn_i.obj, that's why it is "pulled in". This project does not use `/GL` nor `/LTCG` at all (checked the project properties, each cpp file's properties in the project, and there are no "standalone" property sheets in the solution)
- I also tried removing *all* libraries linked to the exe project from it's linkage list. When only the default ones were linked (kernel32.lib, uuid.lib, etc.), the warning still persisted (aside from tons of unresolved references, but that's because I intentionally removed libraries). So it's not external libraries that cause this issue.

Comment: From [/LTCG (Link-time Code Generation)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xbf3tbeh.aspx): *"If you do not explicitly specify **/LTCG** when you pass **/GL** or MSIL modules to the linker, the linker eventually detects this and restarts the link by using **/LTCG**. Explicitly specify **/LTCG** when you pass **/GL** and MSIL modules to the linker for the fastest possible build performance."*

Comment: No repro.  I'd work from the assumption that it fat-fingered the responsible party and it is actually a library you linked that caused unknwn_i.obj to be pulled in.  Linking a library that was compiled with Release build settings (like /GL) is not very healthy btw.

Comment: @HansPassant "it is actually a library you linked that caused unknwn_i.obj to be pulled in" <- Do you mean that a library of mine was actually compiled with `/GL`, but link.exe is blaming unknwn_i.obj for whatever reason?

Comment: Yes.  Consider [this technique](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19493162/17034) to find the troublemaker.

Comment: @HansPassant Looked for the troublemaker, did not find it. I think the troublemaker is not on my end of things :( (see the edits I made)

Comment: Well, keep motoring, you'll discover it some day.  The warning is benign.