# Which static library linked by my compiled exe requires msvcr100d.dll?

Tags: c++, dll, lib

I have a project with over fifty dependencies, most are linked statically. The compiled release exe misses msvcr100d.dll, the debug version. Obviously, the application should not require msvcr100d, since it is a release version (it does require msvcr100).

With dependecy walker I found out that it is the executable itself that requires msvcr100d, not another dll. I am guessing one of the dependency has the wrong configuration or uses some flag such as Multithreaded-Debug-DLL (/MDd) (although I have checked all dependencies for this one), which makes the link to msvcr100d.

Is there a way to find out which static library is responsible for linking to msvcr100d without having to investigate the properties of each and every dependency? Maybe using the info in the pdb-file (which I created for release as well)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19487465/how-to-tell-if-a-lib-was-compiled-with-mt-or-md