# Compile with /MT flag from command line using cmake

Tags: c++, windows, cmake

How can I add the '/MT' flag from the command line using cmake?

Can I simply go `cmake -D CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="/MT" ..`?

In the tutorials I've found online, I see people setting `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE` and `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG` separately and haven't seen any examples with setting it from the command line.

Comment: "Can I simply ..." - Have you **tried** to do that?

Comment: I tried, but I wasn't sure how to validate if it was built with this flag correctly or not.

Comment: And I tried what this answer suggested, using `dumpbin` to check (https://stackoverflow.com/a/19487637/4943329), but I am using circleCI to build the libraries and circleCI windows machine doesn't have that utility installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did some testing, it did not work with `cmake -D CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="/MT" ..` but worked with `cmake -D CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE="/MT" ..`

I verified the resulting library using `dumpbin`.