# Why does linking a library with MSVC work with both `/MD` or `/ML`?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++

As far as I know, when I use a third party library in my project, the runtime library of the project config and the library must be the same (both `/MD` or both `/MT`). But actually it works with the same library, no matter whether `/MD` or `/MT` is used.

Am I misunderstanding something?
Thx.

About the meaning of "with the same library", I mean: one lib file is added to my project, which i don't know whether it is built with "/MD" or "/MT". I just change my project from "/MD" to "/MT", or vice versa. But it always works.

So the conclusion is: Even though it works with diffirent run-time library in a procject, I **shouldn't** do it?

Comment: I assume you mean `/MD` and `/MT` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/md-mt-ld-use-run-time-library?view=msvc-160 If mixed the application can work but there are a number of potential problems regarding memory allocation and deallocation.

Comment: What do you mean with "with the same library"? If your project is compiled with `MD`, you can link with a library compiled with `/MT` and this surprises you?

Comment: @jmon12 From [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/md-mt-ld-use-run-time-library?view=msvc-160): "*all modules passed to a given invocation of the linker must have been compiled with the same run-time library compiler option (`/MD`, `/MT`, `/LD`)*". Combining modules built with different CRT linking options is unsupported and hazardous.

Comment: Thx for answers above. About the meaning of "with the same library", I mean: one lib file is added to my project, which i don't know whether it is built with "/MD" or "/MT".  I just change my project from "/MD" to "/MT", or vice versa. But it always works.

Comment: @Tangtoo You shouldn't mix CRT settings even if it appears to "work", since potential conflicts can be rather obscure and not immediately obvious. Besides, even minor future changes may uncover new incompatibilities. To check how the 3rd party library was built, see for example [How to tell if a lib was compiled with /mt or /md?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19487465/how-to-tell-if-a-lib-was-compiled-with-mt-or-md).